# App crash when npm start using express and nodemon

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a simple `app.js` -

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

//Route
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Welcome to custom api');
})

//Listen
app.listen(3000);
```

My package.json looks like this -

```
{
  "name": "custom-api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "\"API to give custom info\"",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon app.js"
  },
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.2"
  }
}
```

I run `npm start` and get this error -

```
> custom-api@1.0.0 start /Users/workspace/server
> nodemon app.js

[nodemon] 2.0.2
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching dir(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
events.js:187
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3000
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1301:14)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1349:12)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1437:7)
    at Function.listen (/Users/workspace/server/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:618:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/workspace/server/app.js:11:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:959:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1047:10)
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1328:8)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
  code: 'EADDRINUSE',
  errno: 'EADDRINUSE',
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '::',
  port: 3000
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: Use 3001 instead.

Comment: As the error states, something else is already running on port 3000.  If you are on a Mac you can run the following command from a terminal to show you which process is using port 3000 `netstat -vanp tcp | grep 3000` then open Activity Monitor, click on the CPU tab, find that process ID and kill it (or just search for node and kill it).. or you can run this command to just kill whatever is on port 3000 `kill $(lsof -ti:3000)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following error means **3000** is in already use, may be your ran it from another terminal or what or may be some other app is using it.

> Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3000

So try some other port like 3001 or 4000 to see if that works.

Then you can find the process that's already using 3000 and kill it, if it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

> Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3000

Port `3000` is already in use. Either another program is using the port (in which case you'll have to pick another port), or you failed to terminate this program correctly last time you ran it. If you're on linux run `ps` and find the process that was started by the command `nodemon app.js` and copy its `pid`. Then you terminate that process by running `kill` followed by the pid that you just copied.

Ex:

```
$ ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
    8 tty1     00:00:00 bash
   32 tty1     00:00:00 nodemon app.js
   33 tty1     00:00:00 ps

$ kill 32
```